Excel VBA - Skip renaming when cell empty
I use PowerQuery to create a table from databases and manage files.
There are some files I need to move to a specific folder, depending the value in some column. No need in my VBA code to check those, all the various checks are done with PowerQuery.
THere is in fact more column in my table, but the 3 I look at in the macro are those 3.



OriginalNativeName
NewNativeName
completepath\newfolder




complete path folder1Newfilename1
complete path folder1Newfilename1
complete path folder1




complete path folder2


complete path folder1filename 3
complete path folder1Newfilename3
complete path folder1



My VBA code is just to move the files listed in my generated table.  Some line are blank because there is no file or no need to rename ( but other columns are needed, so I cannot delete my line completely).
I need to create the folder, if needed, before moving my files. but I also need to skip the lines that are blank and it's here I have error.
My last attempt as code is the following one, where I try to skip the renaming.
   Sub Move_Native()
   Dim TAncNouv(), L&
   Dim Fobj As Object
   Set Fobj = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
   ChDrive ThisWorkbook.Path: ChDir ThisWorkbook.Path
   TAncNouv = ActiveSheet.Range("xml_ENGDOC[OriginalNativeName]").Resize(, 3).Value
   
   For L = 1 To UBound(TAncNouv, 1)
   If Fobj.FolderExists(TAncNouv(L, 3)) = False Then
   MkDir (TAncNouv(L, 3))
   End If
   If IsEmpty(TAncNouv(L, 1)) = True Then
   
   Else
      
      Name TAncNouv(L, 1) As TAncNouv(L, 2)
      
      End If
      
      Next L
   End Sub

But I still have an Run Time error '75': Path/File access error:

so it means I'm not skipping correctly. What am I doing wrong ? what can I do to skip this part ?
Thanks in advance

Have you checked with the debugger what the content of TAncNouv(L, 1) and TAncNouv(L, 2) is when the error happens? Are the file names valid? Are the paths set correctly? Is there a backslash between path and filename? Is there any locked file?

I'm not sure how to check this precisely with debugger (it send me to the line but I don't know how to see the exact content when error occur ?), but I tried just before sending this request to run the code again. when there was line with empty and line with my files (beginning with empty line) error, no file renamed/moved. When I deleted empty line and run it onloy on lines with file, it was working, no error, file renamed/moved. So it seems it's really the IfEmpty that I'm butchering :/

How to check values with the debugger: (o) Hover with the mouse over the variable, it shows the value. (o) Open the Immediate window (Ctrl+G) and type ? TAncNouv(L, 1) (o) Put statements like Debug.Print TAncNouv(L, 1) in your code (o) Open the locals window (View->Locals Window)   (o) Open the Watch window (View>Watch window)

If you really think that the check for empty is failing: Check carefully the content of the cell. Does it contain any invisible characters (eg spaces, Tabs, Newlines)?

I updated with an image showing when I hover over it>. Error is for TAncNouv(L, 1)="". I inspected better the cell also, but in this case it came from a formula in cell = if (cellx="","",celly) so I'm convinced it is empty,no strange character). Am I making an error in my If statement ? ( I had found here in stackexchange I could you then > nothing Else > my calculation.. but perhaps it was only for some case ?

Skip When Cell Is Blank

A cell is empty when there is nothing in it. Some cells seem to be empty but are not for example cells containing formulas evaluating to ="" or containing "'" or whatnot. Also, the latter cells copied as values will still not become empty.
Power Query copies them exactly as they are (cells can be empty).

To get around this, you could check if their values are equal to "" as illustrated in CLR's answer but I prefer to check if their length is 0.

Additionally, to prevent an error when the cell contains an error, I use the CStr function:
If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) = 0 Then ' is blank
If Len(CStr(cell.Value)) > 0 Then ' is not blank


When dealing with files, there are two main ways in VBA:

Using the Dir and the 'accompanying' VBA functions MkDir, Name, Kill, ... etc.

very efficient
works on a MAC
can't handle unicode characters ('English only')


Using the FileSystemObject object

slower
doesn't work on a MAC
handles unicode characters


Although you can use both ways interchangeably, you would want to be consistent about it by using one or the other.


The following solutions are not tested (the code compiled)!

Note that existing (new) files will be overwritten!


At the Top of the Module
Option Explicit

Private Enum PathColumns
    OldFile = 1
    NewFile = 2
    NewFolder = 3
End Enum

Dir Function
Sub MoveNativeFilesDir()
    
    Const TABLE_NAME As String = "xml_ENGDOC"
    Const FIRST_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "OriginalNativeName"
    Const COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 3 ' consecutive columns
    
    Dim TAncNouv() As Variant:
    TAncNouv = Application.Range(TABLE_NAME).ListObject _
        .ListColumns(FIRST_COLUMN_TITLE).DataBodyRange _
        .Resize(, COLUMNS_COUNT).Value
    
    Dim tRow As Long
    Dim OldFilePath As String, NewFolderPath As String, NewFilePath As String
    
    For tRow = 1 To UBound(TAncNouv, 1)
        OldFilePath = CStr(TAncNouv(tRow, PathColumns.OldFile))
        If Len(OldFilePath) > 0 Then
            If Len(Dir(OldFilePath)) > 0 Then ' old file exists
                NewFolderPath = CStr(TAncNouv(tRow, PathColumns.NewFolder))
                ' Note that the following 'If' statement will fail
                ' if the parent folder (e.g. `C:\Test1`) of the folder
                ' to be created (e.g. 'C:\Test1\Test2') doesn't exist!
                If Len(Dir(NewFolderPath, vbDirectory)) = 0 Then ' doesn't exist
                    MkDir NewFolderPath
                'Else ' new folder exists
                End If
                NewFilePath = CStr(TAncNouv(tRow, PathColumns.NewFile))
                If Len(Dir(NewFilePath)) > 0 Then ' new file exists
                    Kill NewFilePath ' delete
                'Else ' new file doesn't exist
                End If
                Name OldFilePath As NewFilePath ' move
            'Else ' old file doesn't exist
            End If
        'Else ' blank cell
        End If
    Next tRow
            
    MsgBox "Native files moved.", vbInformation

End Sub

FileSystemObject Object
Sub MoveNativeFilesFso()
    
    Const TABLE_NAME As String = "xml_ENGDOC"
    Const FIRST_COLUMN_TITLE As String = "OriginalNativeName"
    Const COLUMNS_COUNT As Long = 3 ' consecutive columns
    
    Dim TAncNouv() As Variant:
    TAncNouv = Application.Range(TABLE_NAME).ListObject _
        .ListColumns(FIRST_COLUMN_TITLE).DataBodyRange.Resize(, COLUMNS_COUNT)
    
    Dim fso As Object: Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    
    Dim tRow As Long
    Dim OldFilePath As String, NewFolderPath As String, NewFilePath As String
    
    For tRow = 1 To UBound(TAncNouv, 1)
        OldFilePath = CStr(TAncNouv(tRow, PathColumns.OldFile))
        If Len(OldFilePath) > 0 Then
            If fso.FileExists(OldFilePath) Then ' old file exists
                NewFolderPath = CStr(TAncNouv(tRow, PathColumns.NewFolder))
                ' Note that the following 'If' statement will fail
                ' if the parent folder (e.g. `C:\Test1`) of the folder
                ' to be created (e.g. 'C:\Test1\Test2') doesn't exist!
                If Not fso.FolderExists(NewFolderPath) Then ' ... doesn't exist
                    fso.CreateFolder NewFolderPath
                'Else ' new folder exists
                End If
                NewFilePath = CStr(TAncNouv(tRow, PathColumns.NewFile))
                If fso.FileExists(NewFilePath) Then ' new file exists
                    fso.CopyFile OldFilePath, NewFilePath, True ' overwrite
                    fso.DeleteFile OldFilePath, True ' also delete if read-only
                Else ' new file doesn't exist
                    fso.MoveFile OldFilePath, NewFilePath
                End If
            'Else ' old file doesn't exist
            End If
        'Else ' blank cell
        End If
    Next tRow
            
    MsgBox "Native files moved.", vbInformation

End Sub


I was rereading for the 4th time to search for OldFile NewFile etc denomination... when I realised it was the enumeration at the beginning (outside the Sub itself.. oops).     Thanks a lot for pointing out the 2 system I was using and their difference, and to do all this work of cleaning my code <3

IsEmpty function - taken from learn.Microsoft.com

When a cell is entirely empty, i.e. when a worksheet is created, or the cell contents are deleted - the cell can be considered explicitly set to Empty and your script would work correctly.
However, if the cell contains a value, string or formula (no matter what the result of that formula), the cell no longer holds that IsEmpty status.
So if cell A1 is completely empty, and cell B1 contains the formula =A1  then IsEmpty(A1) would return True, but IsEmpty(B1) would return False.
To test if a cell (or in this case the array's element) contains no data, use:
If TAncNouv(L, 1) = vbNullString


@VBasic2008: Was about to write the same. Figured out in the meantime why IsEmpty is failing: If you have a cell with a formula and the formula resolves into an empty string, IsEmpty is returning False. So the solution is correct, the explanation is wrong.
